# Method "not available on iOS"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I heard about a function on `NSCalendar` that had been introduced in iOS7.

Had a look in the docs and couldn't find it. Nor in the OS X docs.

The function is `- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date1 equalToDate:(NSDate *)date2 toUnitGranularity:(NSCalendarUnit)unit` i.e. are these two dates on the same day/in the same week/ month, etc...

However, when I try to use it in Xcode 5. The AutoComplete shows it with a red strike through and then when I actually use it I get this error...

[image]

It's odd as the function is clearly there I'm just not able to use it.

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where did you hear about that method? It's possible that the method has been removed during the betas of iOS 7.

It's private API: [__NSCFCalendar.h](https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/__NSCFCalendar.h)

Comment: I saw a tweet a couple days ago. That makes sense. Oh well, I guess we'll have to wait a little longer before using this. What an awesome method to not be able to use. :(

Comment: In the cached version of NSHipster's article about iOS 7 there's a reference to this method (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://nshipster.com/ios7/) but it has been removed. Most probable the method has been public in one of the betas of iOS 7 and might reappear in a future release.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately it's not available for iOS, only for OS X 10.9. You can always dupe [rdar://14995171](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5813401443893248) to tell Apple that you want it for iOS as well.

If you look in NSCalendar.h in the iOS 7 SDK you will see that these methods are tagged as available since `__NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_7_0` which if you look at the top of the same file is defined as

```
#if !defined(__NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_4_0)
#if NS_ENABLE_CALENDAR_NEW_API
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_4_0 4_0
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_5_0 5_0
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_6_0 6_0
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_7_0 7_0
#else
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_4_0 NA
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_5_0 NA
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_6_0 NA
#define __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_7_0 NA
#endif
#endif
```

This currently evaluates to `NA` meaning that these methods are "not available" for iOS.

Comment: @Fogmeister Me too (hence the original radar)

Comment: Hey, I thought I'd point you in the direction of my blog. I just created a category on NSDate that works in exactly the same way... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/nsdate-isequaltodatetounitgranularity/ Hope you find it useful.

Comment: @Fogmeister Nice. Is there an RSS button that I'm not seeing somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to add one but for some reason it doesn't seem to work :(